# cannot set a background for ng-sidebar

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am attempting to set up a ng-sidebar on my page, and while I have it kind of working there is no background to the sidebar, and I cannot assign a colour to it in the CSS. I have been able to assign a background colour via inspect element in chrome. My code is below:

module

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ImageBrowseSidebarComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        SidebarModule.forRoot()
    ],
    exports: [ImageBrowseSidebarComponent]
})

export class ImageBrowseSidebarModule {
}
```

html

```
<ng-sidebar-container style="height: 100em">
    <ng-sidebar [(opened)]="_opened">
       test
    </ng-sidebar>

    <div ng-sidebar-content>
        <button (click)="_toggleSidebar()">Toggle sidebar</button>
    </div>

</ng-sidebar-container>
```

css

```
.ng-sidebar{
    background-color: darkslategray !important;
}
```

Comment: Where is class `ng-sidebar` being added? Or remove `.` from `.ng-sidebar` since it is selector for class and you are targeting the element tag.

Comment: I update the question to make that more clear, and I tried your suggestion and no change

Comment: Can you create a demo at https://stackblitz.com to reproduce the issue that you are facing?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8w2sde?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

it is working on here, but not in my app somehow

Answer (score 2):

For changing the background of sidebar you can do following:

`::ng-deep aside {
  background-color:#FF0000;
  padding: 2em 1em;
}`